# dynamically added radio buttons onclick event not working?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying following, 
1. Get response using Ajax from the users selection which returns me the list of the radio buttons attributes as 
2. Once i get the attribute list i am creating the radio buttons using createElement() 
3. Then i am attaching the event to the radio button for onclick buttons. 
4. Then i add element to the DOM using appedChild

The below is code for adding radio button (for IE)

```
var radio = '<input ';
radio += 'type ="radio" ';
radio += 'id="' + id + '" ';
radio += 'value="" ';
radio += '/>';
radioButton = document.createElement(radio);
radioButton.onClick = function(){alert('this is test')}
ele.appendChild(radioButton);
ele.innerHTML += 'none' + '<br/>';
```

Now in all this when i am adding the radio button to the DOM onclick is not working and i don't understand why ?

Thanks all

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can dynamically add en element to the DOM by two ways: by inserting an html code into the parent element or by creating a child element with some properties. In your example the two methods are mixed - therefore senseless.

Method 1. Inserting HTML code:

```
var radio = '<input type ="radio" id="' + id + '" value="" />';
ele.innerHTML = radio;
document.getElementById(id).onclick = function(){ alert('this is test'); };
```

Method 2. Creating DOM child:

```
var radioButton = document.createElement('input');
radioButton.type = "radio";
radioButton.id = id;
radioButton.onclick = function(){ alert('this is test'); };
ele.appendChild(radioButton);
```

Answer (score 0):

The property is called `onclick` not `onClick`