# Why am I not able to add click event to dynamically inserted element of a list?

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, addeventlistener

I have code shown below for a project where I insert list elements using javascript and for click on each element I have to call a function. However, it does not seem to work.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("content");

c.innerHTML += "<ul>";
        
for(var j = 0; j<5; j++){
          
    c.innerHTML += "<li id = '" + j +  "'>some stuff"+j+"</li>";
    
    document.getElementById(j).addEventListener("click", function(){ alert('this is test'); }, false);
      
  
}
c.innerHTML += "</ul>";
```

```html
<div id = "content"> </div>
```

Why is the click event not being triggered? How can I make this work?

Comment: Why are you not using Jquery? Is there any particular reason?

Comment: this is for a chrome extension. I could use jquery. But can I not do this without jquery? Why should I use jquery? But more importantly I want to know why does this code not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the OP doesn't work is because of this:

```
c.innerHTML += "<li id = '" + j +  "'>some stuff"+j+"</li>";
```

When you concatenate to the innHTML property like that, the element content is first serialised, which removes any listeners that aren't inline (e.g. those added by *addEventListener*). So the only one remaining at the end of the loop is the last one.

But then you do:

```
c.innerHTML += "</ul>";
```

which removes the last one too.

Far better to build a single string of markup and use *innerHTML* once.

Consider: what should the browser do with the opening UL tag until the closing tag is entered? You've added invalid markup to the document, so it has to use error correction to make something work, so you might end up with a structure that isn't what you expected.

For the listeners, you can include them in-line with the rest of the markup so they survive being serialised and parsed.

Alternatively, use DOM methods to create the elements and stop using *innerHTML*.

```js
function doClick(){
  alert('this is a test ' + this.id);
}

window.onload = function() {
  var c = document.getElementById("content");
  var list = document.createElement('ul');
       
  for(var j = 0; j<5; j++){
    var li = list.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
    li.textContent = 'some stuff ' + j;
    li.id = j;
    li.addEventListener('click', doClick, false);
  }
  c.appendChild(list);
};
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a function and use it `onclick`. You can also pass `this`(the element) as argument to the function where you can get the object attributes in that function.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("content");

c.innerHTML += "<ul>";
        
for(var j = 0; j<5; j++){
          
    c.innerHTML += "<li id = '" + j +  "' onclick='alertMe(this)'>some stuff"+j+"</li>";
      
  
}
c.innerHTML += "</ul>";

function alertMe(obj){
alert('this is test from '+obj.id);
}
```

```html
<div id = "content"> </div>
```

**addEventListener Method**:-

document.getElementById can only be called once you have append it into your DOM. before appending to the DOM you cant access it

If you still want to use `addEventListener` you can achieve by adding listener after appending the element like below

```js
var c = document.getElementById("content");

c.innerHTML += "<ul>";
        
for(var j = 0; j<5; j++){
          
    c.innerHTML += "<li id = '" + j +  "'>some stuff"+j+"</li>";
    
    document.getElementById(j).addEventListener("click", function(){ alert('this is test'); }, false);
      
  
}
c.innerHTML += "</ul>";
```

```html
<div id = "content"> </div>
```

```js
var c = document.getElementById("content");
c.innerHTML += "<ul>";
for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
  c.innerHTML += "<li id = '" + j + "'>some stuff" + j + "</li>";
}
c.innerHTML += "</ul>";
for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
  document.getElementById(j).addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert('this is test');
  }, false);
}
```

```html
<div id="content"> </div>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById`  can only be called once you have append it into your DOM. before appending to the DOM you cant access it. Updated the answer in your way ^

Comment: but did i not add the html and then add the event listener? or maybe I am thinking something completely wrong here

Comment: Look at the first answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475314/dynamically-added-radio-buttons-onclick-event-not-working

Comment: Yes he is using `onclick` after `ele.innerHTML = radio;`, right? once he set it in innerHTML it will be get added to the DOM. so that he can add an event listener

Comment: wait why does it work when you use a separate loop for adding the listener?

Comment: DOM elements should be proper. before writing `</ul>` you are getting the element which wont be a proper approach

Answer (score 0):

Try understand following magic

```js
var c = document.getElementById("content");

c.innerHTML += "<ul>";
        
for(var j = 0; j<5; j++){
    c.innerHTML += "<li id = '" + j +  "'>some stuff"+j+"</li>";
}
c.innerHTML += "</ul>";

setTimeout(function () {
 for(var j = 0; j<5; j++){    
    document.getElementById(j).addEventListener("click", function(){ alert('this is test'); }, false);    
  }
});
```

```html
<div id = "content"> </div>
```

Comment: why does this work? I do not understand. aren't you just using a separate for loop? what is the explanation for this?